# c++ how to pass 2D array to function with variables that the user enters?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

When I run the following code I get an error at the function.

```
using namespace std;

void function(int a[rows][columns]) {}

int main() {
    int rows, columns;
    cin >> rows >> columns;

    int matrix[rows][columns];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    function(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

How do I pass the 2D array to the function with variables that the user enters?

Comment: This `int matrix[rows][columns];` is not valid C++, so your question is moot.

Comment: This `void function(int a[rows][columns])`would even not work in C, except if `rows`and `columns`are global variables.

Comment: In C++ you should use `vector<vector<int>>` or better an object Matrix that you define yourself or find in a library. If you are forced to use C-style array, use `int **a` ... but you will go into trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vector<vector<int>>` like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void function(const vector<vector<int>>& a) {}

int main() {
    int rows, columns;
    cin >> rows >> columns;

    int initial_value = 0;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;
    matrix.resize(rows, std::vector<int>(columns, initial_value));

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    function(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```